# How can I launch a specific application bypassing the global menu in Unity?

Tags: menu, latex, gvim

So, trying to get up to speed with LaTex in vim/gvim... problem is the beginners tutorial for vim-latexsuite assumes gvim and the gui menus. Okay, got gvim right here. Problem is, under Unity and the global app menu, the menus are truncated and don't show the keyboard shortcuts that they should for most entries, or in the case of the TeX-Suite menus, entries like `'2: Article' are simply truncated to '2: '.` Not helpful at all!

I know the menus themselves work - starting gvim using `sudo gvim`, which does not use the global app menu but the local menus, looks just fine - like gvim on any other platform or desktop, i.e. like it should.

How do I force that behaviour under Unity for a regular user (i.e. not using sudo)?

Comment: See updated answer, @Braiam suggested a much better and simpler approach.

Comment: And @Braiam saved the day again, see updated answer for how to get it to work graphically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work ([thanks @Braiam](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14272388#14272388)):

```
 UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 gvim
```

Running the above command from a terminal will launch a `gvim` instance with its own menus. So, to create a launcher on your desktop, open a file called `~/Desktop/gvim.desktop` with the following contents:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=gvim
    Comment=Run gvim with menus
    Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 gvim
    Type=Application
    Icon=/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/48x48/apps/vim.png
    StartupNotify=true
    Categories=Utility;Editor;
```

The `env` command allows you to run a specific command in a temporarily modified environment and is needed to pass the variable when you launch a program using a `.desktop` file.

If you prefer the command line way, you now make an alias for the command above by adding this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias gvim="UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 gvim"
```

Now, open a new terminal, run `gvim` and you'll have it menu free.

Comment: Since I'm effectively the only user on this machine, I skipped the bit with editing /etc/sudoers but otherwise it worked great.  Its unfortunate that Ubuntu/Unity insists on 'dumbing down' the menus in various apps like this...

Comment: @memilanuk the sudoers thing is just so you can run it without having to enter a password, nothing to do with other users, just you. And yes, Unity is far from my preferred desktop environment.

Comment: I'd gotten to like XFCE quite a bit in 12.04 and 12.10... but on this laptop (new around then), some of the Fn keys didn't work quite right in Xubuntu and did in Ubuntu/Unity for some reason.  Kind of wanting to migrate back to Xubuntu; tried installing xubuntu-desktop but it didn't work.  I think when Xubuntu 14.04LTS comes out I'll do a fresh install and call it good for the remaining life of the machine (another couple years at least - I hope).

Comment: @memilanuk don't forget you can install any desktop environment you want. There is no reason to use unity if you don't want to.

Comment: *Why* does `sudo` help here? I guess because it almost clears the environment? What environment variable is the culprit — `env -u DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS gvim` perhaps?

Comment: @Gilles I have absolutely no idea. Some kind of internal Unity thing apparently. I only did this cause the OP said that it works that way with `sudo` (and I tested in a VM and lo! So it does!).

Comment: Well, does it work with `env -i PATH=$PATH HOME=$HOME DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY` (and maybe a couple more)?

Comment: @terdon Could you clarify where that `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 gvim` bit is supposed to go?

Comment: @memilanuk straight into the terminal, that's the exact command that you should run. See updated answer for a few more details, you can make an alias to simplify things. Can't get it to work for a desktop launcher though so, unless someone has a clever idea, you'll have to use the `sudo` trick for that.

Comment: Hmmm... bummer that the first way won't work for the desktop or dock launchers.  Guess I'll have to keep my new 'custom' launcher on the dock for now ;)

Is this the sort of thing that the new 'local menus' feature I'm reading about in the upcoming 14.04LTS should remedy?

Comment: @memilanuk there's probably a trick but I haven't thought of one. And no idea about the 14.04, don't tell anyone but I don't actually use Ubuntu, I only have a virtual machine running to answer the occasional question here :).

Comment: Hey, if you can whip out quick answers like that from just running it occasionally in a VM, its all the more impressive as far as I'm concerned! ;)  Like I said, I'm going to take a long hard look at migrating when the LTS comes out and has had some time to settle down.  Laptop hardware is kind of fussy and Ubuntu/Unity was the only distro I found that supported mine close to 100% wheen I got it 1.5yr ago.

Comment: @memilanuk I do use Linux mind, just not Ubuntu. I switched to Ubuntu from SuSe a few years after it came out cause it was better at dealing with my laptop's hardware and switched to Mint later cause it was _even_ better at it. I'm using LMDE now (a Mint-flavored Debian, not Ubuntu based). Does the new solution work for you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13594/discussion-between-memilanuk-and-terdon)